# How to display messages "properly" when using ajax submit?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

Here is a simple form:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $form['some_text'] = [
      '#type'  => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('TextValue'),
    ];
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type'  => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    if ($form_state->getValue('some_text') != 'Awesome') {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('some_text', $this->t('Please enter "Awesome"'));
    }
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    drupal_set_message($this->t('The form was submitted'));
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromRoute('<front>'));
  }
```

And it works as expected:
Case 1A: Submit with no entry gives this (error message in default message location):
[image]
Case 1B: Submit with "Awesome" in `TextValue` gives this (completion message  in default message location and back to the front page of the site):
[image]
Now, I add some ajax on the submit button:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type'  => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
  '#ajax'  => [
    'wrapper'  => 'default_form_wrapper',
    'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
    'progress' => [
      'type'    => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Be patient'),
    ],
  ],
];
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="default_form_wrapper">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

and the corresponding callback:

```
  public function ajaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
      return $form;
    }
  }
```

And it works more or less as expected:
Case 2A: Submit with no entry gives this (almost OK, wrong location of the message):
[image]
Case 2B: Submit with "Awesome" in `TextValue` gives nothing (KO, no message and form is still displayed instead of front page).
And if I refresh the page in the browser, I get this:
[image]
As you can see, the location of the message area in case 2A is above form in `default_form_wrapper`
(to be compared to the default message area location, a div with class="region region-highlighted"):
[image]
[image]

How can I make it work as I expect?

1. Have the message in the "default" area?
2. Have my `submitForm` work after all?

Comment: Does the issue still occur when using the default Bartik theme?

Comment: Exactly same behavior with Bartik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after hours digging Drupal Answers, I made it work this way.
My `ajaxCallback`:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
  $messages = \Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();
  $messages = [
    '#theme'        => 'status_messages',
    '#message_list' => $messages,
  ];
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#messages', ''));
  $response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('.region-highlighted', $messages));
}
else {
  $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\RedirectCommand(Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString()));
  }
}
return $response;
```

and my `submitForm` is now empty!

Nota: `$response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#messages', ''));` is here to have a new error message replacing a previous one (without this command, all the messages are displayed one after the other...).